# How to register a separate xib cells to multiple tableviews?

Tags: swift, xcode, uitableview, swift4, xib

I have two tableviews with two xib cells. How do I register the second xib cell with the second table?

It keeps putting in the cell from the first table.

This is my code:

```
let cellNib = UINib(nibName: "FirstTableViewCell", bundle: nil)
self.tableView.register(cellNib, forCellReuseIdentifier: "cell")

let cellNib2 = UINib(nibName: "SecondViewCell", bundle: nil)
self.secondTableView.register(cellNib2, forCellReuseIdentifier: "cell2")
```

Here's my cellForRowAt function:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {


if tableView == tableView {
 let cell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! FirstTableViewCell



    return cell
}

else  {
    let cell2 = self.secondTableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell2", for: indexPath) as! SecondViewCell

     return cell2
}

}
```

Comment: what do you mean "it keeps putting in the first xib"? are you saying that the first table view cell is being registered for both tables? How do you know this?

Comment: Yeah the first one is being registered for both. When I run it, the first cell appears in both tables. The one with identifier “cell”

Comment: can you show us your `cellForIndexAt` function? add the code snippet to your question, please

Comment: Edited my code snippet to add the cellForRowAt

Answer (score 2):

In your `cellForRowAt` function, there is a local variable called `tableView` (look at the function header, `tableView` is the name of the first parameter), so the check `tableView == tableView` is always going to return true. This is why you will always get the first cell.

Replace that line with:

`if tableView == self.tableView {}`

By adding the `self`, you are directly referencing the class variable `tableView` instead of the local variable. Hope this helps.